# Clear Cookie - using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

Here my jsp code but i want to use javascript in some ways

```
    Cookie[] delCookies = request.getCookies(); 
try { 
    for( Cookie cookie : delCookies) { 
        cookie.setMaxAge(0); 
        response.addCookie(cookie); 
    } 
}catch(Exception e) { 
    System.out.println("del:::cookieValue::exception:::"+e); 
}
```

//Can you do it in javascript !!

Thz in advance for helping

Answer (score 1):

Deleting a cookie is very simple. Just set the expires parameter to a passed date:

```
document.cookie = "username=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
```

**Note** that you don't have to specify a cookie value when you delete a cookie.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp